# onbindViewHolder is not accepting view holder variables

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason the on bindviewholder is not accepting the variables created by Viewholder(holder.name and holder.dexription). I have tried everything to fix it but nothing has worked Here is the code if you could help I would be grateful.

```
public class CityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<City> cities;
        public CityAdapter(ArrayList<City> cities) {
            this.cities =cities;
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (cities != null) {
            return cities.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
       View v =(View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);
       return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        City city = cities.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(city.getName());
        holder.description.setText(city.getDescription());
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public View view;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            this.description=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            this.image=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Because your ViewHolder class is static

Comment: Also, Change your custom ViewHolder class to something different to avoid confusion

Comment: i have changed it from static but it still doesn't work

Comment: Change your custom ViewHolder class name to something like MyViewHolder. Then change the extend part to

CityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CityAdapter.MyViewHolder>

Comment: Change your import from RecyclerView.ViewHolder to CityAdapter.ViewHolder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are extending from wrong class

change `CityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>`
to

```
CityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CityAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

And change your "onBindViewHolder" method's first argument from

`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

to

```
ViewHolder
```